# Symfony2 - My service is not registered

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

Surely a dumb thing but I'm not able to register `MyService` from `MyBundle`

**src/Me/MyBundle/**

```
$ ls -R src/Me/MyBundle/

DependencyInjection/
    MeMyBundleExtension.php
    Configuration.php
Resources/
    config/
        services.yml
Services/
    MyService.php
MyBundle.php
```

**src/Me/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MeMyBundleExtension.php**

```php
namespace Me\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

// standard stuff

class MeMyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // standard stuff loading the yml file
    }
}
```

**src/Me/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

```php
namespace Me\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_services');

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**src/Me/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```yml
services:
    me.myservice:
        class: Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService
```

**src/Me/MyBundle/Services/MyService.php**

```php
namespace Me\MyBundle\Services;

class MyService
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

I can see that my service is not registered when I try to instantiate it from a controler

```
$test = $this->get('me.myservice');
```

> You have requested a non-existent service "me.myservice"

Is there something wrong here ?

---

```
$ php app/console container:debug | grep me.mybundle
```

Nothing matches

Comment: class: Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService.yml => MyService.php
Then check the existence of your service with php app/console container:debug

Comment: Thanx. I did bad copy/pastes, question updated. `php app/console container:debug | grep me.mybundle` doesn't give me any match.

Comment: Did you include the `services.yml` in your `config.yml` and/or your `config_dev.yml`?

Comment: Are you talking about `app/config/config.yml` ?

Answer (score 2):

**src/Me/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    me.myservice:
        class: Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService.yml
```

This should refer a class not a yml-file. So it should be `class: Me\MyBundle\Services\MyService`

Further should you check your namespaces. If your bundle is not a child-bundle (`getParent('SonataUserBundle')`) you should put your classes in your own namespace.

**src/Me/MyBundle/Services/MyService.php**

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Services;
```

**src/Me/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;
```

Also should your `MyBundle.php` be `MeMyBundle.php` according to symfony's naming strategy.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make my copy/pastes well, question updated. +1 for your attention.

Comment: `src/Me/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` still is not in the right namespace.

Comment: Yet another typo. Thanks for this one too. Question updated. (I originally did modifications to simplify the question, explaining the typos)

Comment: if you add a `die()` in the constructor of MeMyBundleExtension get it called? Have you registred your bundle in the `AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Yeah the `die()` doesn't prevent the call. I successfully registered the service from another bundle. It's doesn't work from `MyBundle` (yes it is in the AppKernel, I have doctrine entities already working on it).

Answer (score 1):

There is an automatic mapping thing going on in which the extension class name is derived from the bundle name.  I had trouble with this some time ago.  So I routinely just explicitly specify the extension in the Bundle class.  Something like:

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

use Cerad\Bundle\AppBundle\DependencyInjection\AppExtension;

class CeradAppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new AppExtension();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer just spared me a whole lot of frustration (i was ~20 minutes into this issue). Thanks!